# How to make snippets for json files in VS Code?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

VS code uses JSON files to make snippets. So to make make snippets for a JSON File you need to write in an JSON file.

So, I tried it. This:

```
{
    "snippety":{
        "prefix": "snippet",
        "body": [
            "\"$1\":{",
            "\t\"prefix\": \"$2\",",
            "\t\"body\":[",
            "\t\t\"$3\"",
            "\t],",
            "\t\"description\":\"$4\""
        ],
        "description": "wow"
    }
}
```

But the snippet won't come in the [suggestion list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/815Xq.png).

Comment: where did you put that json in? What file at what path? Please also describe what is happening in your screenshot in words.

Answer (score 1):

Put your snippet into the `jsonc.json` snippets file (that you create with the Gear icon/User Snippets picker with `jsonc`) and then it will work.

The snippets files you are trying to use the snippet in are `jsonc` files, not `json`.

Comment: Note that this answer is in response to the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/815Xq.png) in the question. It appears that the asker is not aware of which [language mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_change-the-language-for-the-selected-file) they're using for the target document.

Comment: Look at the snippet itself - the OP is trying to make a snippet which scaffolds snippets.  So that plus the screenshot makes it evident that he is trying to use his snippet within snippets' files - which are jsonc.